# Split two strings into List<string> and compare using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects with a string property named "Color". I need to split the string into a list using a space delimiter and compare the list to another list to see if any of the contained strings match using Linq.

```
 string searchString = "I like sand";
 List<string> searches = searchString.Split(' ').ToList();

 //Determine if matches exists anywhere between the 2 strings using linq
 List<myObject> obj = myObjectList.Where(x=> searches.Any(a=>x.Color.Contains(a))).Any();
```

Using my current Linq query, I can only find exact matches. So Lets say one my Objects Color properties equaled "sand", the query will return a match, but if my Color equals a two word name like "sand dune" my query will not return a match.

This example should kind of help explain what needs to return as a match.

```
//Two strings should return a match as the word sand is in both
"I like sand"
"sand dune"

//Two strings should NOT return a match as no common words exist
"I like sand"
"Ice cream"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `Intersect()` and `Any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting both strings and then use LINQs `Intersect()` to get splits that are in both strings and `Any()` to check whether there is such an intersection:

```
var first = "I like sand";
var second = "san dune";

var result = first.Split(' ').Intersect(second.Split(' ')).Any();
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I tried Intersect earlier, but must have used it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting on `null` instead of a blank character, that way you split on all whitespace.  You can also extract this into a function:

```
private static bool CompareStrings(string a, string b)
{
    return a.Split(null).Intersect(b.Split(null)).Any();
}
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
bool result = CompareStrings("I like sand", "sand dune");
bool result2 = CompareStrings("I like sand", "Ice cream");
```

Keep in mind this solution will be case sensitive, so `Sand` and `sand` *would not* be a match.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ehEoPR)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion on splitting by 'null' I gave Adrian the answer as it looks like he jumped in first. Good advice as always though thank you!